# Retorno errado JavaScript e PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Olá!

Estou fazendo uso de uma API da tabela FIPE, usando Javascript para obter os dados e passando para minha base de dados via post em PHP.
A questão é que ao passa para o PHP, ele não está enviando o nome do campo e sim o código da API.
Onde estou errando? Conseguem me ajudar por favor?

1. JavaScript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var urlBase = "//fipe.parallelum.com.br/api/v1/carros/marcas";

    /** Marcas**/

    $.getJSON(urlBase, function(data) {
      var items = ["<option value=\"\">ESCOLHA UMA MARCA</option>"];
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items += ("<option value='" + val.codigo + "'>" + val.nome + "</option>");
      });
      $("#marcas").html(items);
    });

    /** Veiculo**/

    $("#marcas").change(function() {
      $.getJSON(urlBase + "/" + jQuery("#marcas").val() + "/" + "modelos", function(data) {
        var items = ["<option value=\"\">ESCOLHA UM VEICULO</option>"];
        $.each(data.modelos, function(key, val) {
          items += ("<option value='" + val.codigo + "'>" + val.nome + "</option>");
        });
        $("#modelos").html(items);
      });
    });

    /** Ano**/

    $("#modelos").change(function() {
      $.getJSON(urlBase + "/" + jQuery("#marcas").val() + "/" + "modelos" + "/" + jQuery("#modelos").val() + "/" + "anos", function(data) {
        var items = ["<option value=\"\">ESCOLHA O ANO</option>"];
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
          //console.log(data)
          items += ("<option value='" + val.codigo + "'>" + val.nome + "</option>");
        });
        $("#ano").html(items);
      });
    });
  });
```

2. cadastrar.php.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 form-group">
                                    <span>Marca</span>
                                    <div class="form-select">
                                        <select name="brand" id="marcas" class="form-control" style="height: 42px;">

                                        </select>
                                        <span class="select-icon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-down"></i></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3 form-group">
                                    <span>Modelo</span>
                                    <div class="form-select">
                                        <select name="model" id="modelos" class="form-control"
                                            style="height: 42px;">

                                        </select>
                                        <span class="select-icon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-down"></i></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
                                    <span>Ano</span>
                                    <div class="form-select">
                                        <select name="year" id="ano" class="form-control" style="height: 42px;">

                                        </select>
                                        <span class="select-icon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-down"></i></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

3. post.php(Recebendo as informações).

```
$placa = test_input($_POST["placa"]);
$marca = test_input($_POST["brand"]);
$modelo = test_input($_POST["model"]);
$ano = test_input($_POST["year"]);
```

4. Na página / na base.

[image: Na página / na base]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sinceramente não entendi o seu problema. Poderia exemplificar melhor?

Comment: @Guerra Claro... No item 4, na minha página de cadastro, no campo marca por exemplo, eu recebo o meu retorno do javascript como texto (Nome da minha marca), mas quando passo para o meu PHP que fara o envio para o banco de dados, ele passa o "Código" da marca e não o "Nome" que está no campo, conforme mostra a última imagem do banco de dados apresentando somente o código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver!

Coloquei essa function para chamar o conteúdo da option.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var marcas = $("#marcas");
        var modelos = $("#modelos");

        var marcaSelecao = $("#marcaSelecao");
        var modeloSelecao = $("#modeloSelecao");

        marcas.change(function(){
            marcaSelecao.val('');
            modeloSelecao.val('');

            var valor = $("#marcas option:selected").html();
            marcaSelecao.val(valor);
        });

        modelos.change(function(){
            var valor = $("#modelos option:selected").html();
            modeloSelecao.val(valor);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/** Marcas**/

    $.getJSON(urlBase, function(data) {
      var items = ["<option value=\"\">ESCOLHA UMA MARCA</option>"];
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items += ("<option value='" + val.codigo + "'>" + val.nome + "</option>");
      });
      $("#marcas").html(items);
    });
```

subistitua por

/** Marcas**/

```
$.getJSON(urlBase, function(data) {
  var items = ["<option value=\"\">ESCOLHA UMA MARCA</option>"];
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items += ("<option value='" + val.nome + "'>" + val.nome + "</option>");
  });
  $("#marcas").html(items);
});
```

você pode substituir em MARCAS/MODELOS e ANO, que seu campo vai receber os valores texto, e não mais os IDs. Dessa maneira não precisa dessa função para pegar o selected e substituir na hora de enviar....